# Is it possible to dynamically type the HandleInertiaRequest share function?

Tags: typescript, laravel, inertiajs, laravel-data

I'd like to dynamically type the HandleInertiaRequest share function using Spatie Laravel Data and the Typescript transformer.

This is to have a dynamic type that I can use in my front-end to type the usePage.

My first idea was that `Middleware` from `Inertia` would extend `Data` from `Spatie` and then I could use `#[TypeScript]` for HandleInertiaRequest, but this wasn't the right way.

I don't have enough experience of Inertia to know whether this is possible. Any one have an idea ?

Thank you in advanced